# RestTemplate considering a resource to be a parameter

Tags: rest, resttemplate, web-api-testing

My request goes like this... https://......./results/@codeResults

When i hit this get request with postman, i get the desired output. (Please note that @codeResults is used as it is in the request and is not to be replaced by any value)

But when I try to hit this using exchange method of RestTemplate it says -

Status Code : 400
message: invalid resultId: @codeResults

As an alternative approach, I tried to pass @codeResults as a path param using URIComponentBuilder as well but still I am getting the same issue.

Please provide any pointers on this.

Comment: maybe it needs to be escaped: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: Tried escaping, still the same error